# Issues with xpath context

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a simple xml document:

```xml
<Results>
     <Result>
          <Number>1</Number>
          <Data>a</Data>
     </Result>
     <Result>
          <Number>2</Number>
          <Data>b</Data>
     </Result>
</Results>
```

I'm trying to get the data and number of each result using this code:

```java
XPathExpression resExpr = xpath
        .compile("//Results/Result");
XPathExpression numExpr=xpath
        .compile("//Result/Number");
XPathExpression dataExpr=xpath
        .compile("//Result/Data");
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) resExpr.evaluate(root_node,
        XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++) {

    Node result=nodeList.item(i);

    if (result!=null) {
        Node numNode=(Node)  numExpr.evaluate(result,
                XPathConstants.NODE);
        Node dataNode=(Node)  dataExpr.evaluate(result,
                XPathConstants.NODE);
        String data=dataNode.getTextContent());
        String num=numNode.getTextContent());

    }
}
```

However, I get 1/a on both iterations.  It seem that passing a node doesn't make xpath use it as context, but rather it's looking at whole tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your xpath expression start with `//`. This means start searching from document root any child. 
To access child of current node try  `.//` for child in any deep,  or `./` for direct child.

Or, because the current not in iteration is Result you can use:

```
XPathExpression numExpr=xpath
        .compile("Number");
XPathExpression dataExpr=xpath
        .compile("Data");
```